# Confusion about division in Clifford Algebra

Tags: clifford-algebras, division-algebras

On page 202 of The Road to Reality, Penrose claims that if we want to generalize Quaternions to n dimensions using Clifford Algebra, we must abandon the division property. I have a hard time believing this claim. Would someone who knows about this mind following my reasoning and telling me if I'm wrong?

I recently spent quite a bit of time studying Clifford Algebra, and at it's core is the 'geometric product'. The fact that this product is associative in the algebra is an axiom. The product looks like

\begin{equation}
uv=u \cdot v +u \wedge v
\end{equation}

Hence,
\begin{equation}
 u^2=u \cdot u +u \wedge u = u \cdot u
\end{equation}

Now consider

\begin{equation}
w=uv
\end{equation}

I can divide w by v to get back u as follows (if |v|=/=0):

\begin{equation}
\frac{w}{v}=\frac{wv}{v^2 }=\frac{(uv)v}{v^2  }
\end{equation}

Now, since our geometric product is associative,

\begin{equation}
\frac{w}{v}=\frac{(uv)v}{v^2 }= \frac{u(vv)}{v^2}=u
\end{equation}
Voila!

Nowhere in that argument did I need to restrict the dimensionality of my clifford algebra, I needed only the most basic properties of the geometric product, it's associativity and decomposition in the scalar and wedge products.

Can anyone weigh in on why people like Penrose seem to think that one can't divide in n dimensional Clifford algebra?

Comment: Hm, I see that if I work in a Clifford Algebra as Penrose does where the basis elements have negative square, ie.  $\gamma_i^2=-1$ that there is a possibility of degeneracy in |v|^2 which could spoil the property of division. However, geometric algebra people much more commonly use an algebra where $\gamma_i^2=1$ but $\gamma_i \gamma_j=-\gamma_j \gamma_i$for i not equal to j. This algebra very cleanly describes euclidean space and here you are guaranteed that v^2=0 if and only if v=0, so I fail to see why I don't have a notion of division here in n dimensions.

Comment: You may be interested in reading about the [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)) which concludes that a finite dimensional, associative $\Bbb R$-division-algebra is exactly one of three things: $\Bbb R, \Bbb C$, or $\Bbb H$. "Geometric algebras" are all associative $\Bbb R$ algebras (usually finite dimensional) of course, and these three are "geometric algebras," but none of the other real geometric algebras can be division algebras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not every element of a Clifford algebra has the form $v$ for $v$ a vector. In general an element of a Clifford algebra is a sum of products of such things, and most of these aren't invertible.

Explicitly, let $\text{Cliff}(p, q)$ be the Clifford algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ generated by $p$ generators $e_1, \dots e_p$ satisfying $e_i^2 = -1$ and $q$ generators $f_1, \dots f_q$ satisfying $f_i^2 = 1$, all of which anticommute. If $q \neq 0$ then $f_i^2 = 1$ implies $(f_i + 1)(f_i - 1) = 0$, so $f_i \pm 1$ fail to be invertible.

So now let $q = 0$; the corresponding Clifford algebra is often denoted $\text{Cliff}(p)$. When $p = 1$ we get $\mathbb{C}$ and when $p = 2$ we get $\mathbb{H}$; these are division algebras. It turns out that for $p = 3$ we have

$$\text{Cliff}(3) \cong \mathbb{H} \times \mathbb{H}$$

which is not a division algebra. Explicitly, once you have three anticommuting square roots of $-1$, namely $e_1, e_2, e_3$, you can now write down

$$(e_1 e_2 e_3)^2 = 1$$

and so $e_1 e_2 e_3 \pm 1$ fails to be invertible.

Comment: Sorry with my unfamiliarity but is it standard to write that direct sum with a $\times$?

Comment: @Tyler: direct sum names a vector space, but direct product names a ring, and I'm naming a ring here.

Comment: Apologies...I didn't realize that the two, one considered as an algebra and the other a ring, are isomorphic

Comment: I see! So even though the vector part of the algebra is guaranteed to have a multiplicative inverse for a nonzero vector, you can cook up multi vectors which don't have inverses. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check for yourself that in $G^3$  that is the Pauli algebra with basis $ e_1, e_2, e_3$ 
$
(1+ e_1) (1 - e_1) =0
$ .
The claim is that there are zero divisors, not it is impossible in principle to divide two elements.